# Playing a remote mp3 file with buffering/streaming chunks

Tags: iphone, ios, streaming, avaudioplayer, buffering

I'm currently using CocosDenshion for small sound effects (half a second long), And now
I need to play short 30-second audio clips (mp3) that are hosted on a server, not inside the app resource bundle. I'm trying to get some code to play it with two "requirements":

1. that it plays as it loads, so i wouldn't have to wait for the entire thing to load just to play it.
2. That it would have some sort of delegate to show the progress of the played track.

I've tried using AVAudioPlayer but it doesnt work for me, plus it doesn't "Buffer" the data, it waits for the entire thing to load (Tried on simulator, if it matters). What i tried is:

```cpp
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender{
    NSString *_mp3file = @"http://www.somesite.com/somefile.mp3";
    NSData *_mp3data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: _mp3file]];

    NSError *error;

    AVAudioPlayer *avp = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:_mp3data error:&error];
    avp.numberOfLoops = 0;
    avp.volume = 1.0f;
    avp.delegate = self;
    [avp prepareToPlay];

    if(avp == nil)
        GTMLoggerError(@"%@", error);
    else
        [avp play];
}
```

Would love your help an experience on this :)
Cheers, 
Shai.

Comment: you can try [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your didLoad method

```
dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = 
dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^(void){
    NSString *_mp3file = @"http://cs4405.vk.me/u360087/audios/4efe178f2608.mp3";
    NSData   *_mp3Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: _mp3file]];
    NSError  *_error   = nil;

    self._audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:_mp3Data error:&_error];

    if (self._audioPlayer != nil)
    {
        self._audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        if ([self._audioPlayer prepareToPlay] && [self._audioPlayer play])
        {
            NSLog(@"Successfully started playing");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to play");
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed to instanciate player");
    }
});
```

Comment: I actually used Tushar's solution (in the comment above) but thanks anyways!